# How do I replace a value in one cell based on value in another cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function CopyinData_AM_A() {
/* Edit the vars below this line for your needs */
var sourceSheet  = "Students AM" ;  // Enter the name of the sheet with the source data
var sourceRange = "B7:N77" ; // Enter the range of the cells with the source data
var targetSheet = "Students AM A" ; // Enter the name of the target sheet
var targetRange = "B7:N77" ; // Enter the range of cells you wish to copy data to. Note this must be same size as source range.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
var values = sheet.getRange(sourceRange).getValues();
ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(targetRange).setValues(values);
}
```

How would I add this into the above script? The action needs to occur after the data is copied into the sheet. I am only a VB coder. 'Students AM A' is a formula free sheet.

```
      For each cell in ‘Students AM A'!N7:N77 then
              If Ncell= ‘Menu!D14' then Hcell = ”O"
              Check next cell
      End
```

I'd have zero issue doing this in VB, I just started using google scripts about 3 months ago. Anyone recommend a good book to assist me in learning this google script stuff?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, David! A pointer to remember, it might be more helpful if your posts are kept to the point. Questions like book and tutorial recommendations might not be appropriate here, since we aim solely to provide coding assistance. These might be better fit for a forum. I say this because you might risk the closure of a question if it is flagged as being off-topic or unclear. Do keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Once you have a value range, you can loop through the rows and compare the values against the reference value

You can use e.g. a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp), a conditonal [if statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) and the `==` [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison)

Sample to be merged with the rest of your function:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet  = ss.getSheetByName("Students AM");
var referenceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Menu");
var referenceValue = referenceSheet.getRange("D14").getValue();
var sourceRange = "B7:N77";
var values = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRange).getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
// values[i][12] correspond to the values in column N of each row
  if(values[i][12] == referenceValue){
    sourceSheet.getRange((sourceRange + i), 7).setValue("O");
  }
}
```

For further reading:

- [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)